Flutter - Fit a video within a SizedBox
I am using Chewie to display videos in my Flutter app. I have a full screen videos that looks like the image below:

I want to display the videos in the following format with a 1:1 aspect ratio.
Is it possible to achieve this automatically using Chewie without stretching or compressing the video  or is there another way to achieve this. I tried various solutions I found online using AspectRatio, FittedBox and SizedBox.expanded widgets without any success.


most likely you may use thumbnail instead of player here

Here's a combined approach that incorporates the best aspects of previous suggestions and addresses potential issues:

Manually Initialize VideoPlayerController:

Chewie's autoInitialize property might not always wait for the video's actual aspect ratio. To ensure control, manually initialize the VideoPlayerController:
final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(yourVideoUrl);

Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
  await videoPlayerController.initialize();
  setState(() {});} // Rebuild the widget with the aspect ratio

Call initializePlayer() in your initState or a similar lifecycle method.

Use AspectRatio with videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio:

Wrap the Chewie widget with an AspectRatio widget:
AspectRatio(
aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
child: Chewie(...),),// Your Chewie configuration

This ensures the Chewie widget respects the video's natural aspect ratio within the AspectRatio container.
3. Optional: Constrain Within a Container (if needed):
If you need further control over the video's placement, wrap the AspectRatio widget with a Container:
Container(
width: double.infinity,
height: double.infinity,
 child: AspectRatio(
aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
child: Chewie(...),),),

This ensures the video fills the available space while maintaining its aspect ratio within the container.

Steps 1 and 2 work well, but I am getting an error "BoxConstraints forces an infinite height." when I add the Container. How do I resolve this?
